# Samoa: Teuila Festival 2023

Tags: samoa

Would like to visit the Teuila festival in Samoa this year (2023), but can't find details about this year's event.

Is the Teuila festival happening this year (2023)? What are the dates?

Is there a program of events?

Comment: I am a little surprised you cannot find details - a google search showed me various sites with info and travel organisations with itineraries etc

Comment: @RoryAlsop Great! Obviously you're a better Googler than me. Could you please send me the urls of those sites. esp. if they have a program for the 2023 festival.